# React Native - Send message via whats app bussines

Tags: react-native, whatsapp, whatsapi

React Native: I would like to create a link that prepares to send a message via whatsapp.

I am doing it as follows :

```js
Linking.openURL(`whatsapp://send?text=${message}&phone=+55${masked}`);
```

My question is how to adapt this code and open WhatsAppBussines?

Answer (score 2):

something like this

```js
<Text style={{color: 'blue'}}
onPress={() => Linking.openURL('whatsapp://send?text=${message}&phone=+55${masked}')}>
  Whatsapp
</Text>
```

and when you click, WhatsApp auto open, you can choose whatsapp/whatsappbusiness

Comment: Thanks for your contribution!

in my case, does not ask which to use, always uses whatsapp